# Prevent Power Query from adding empty columns after the last column of imported data

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am importing a CSV from a folder.

The CSV Data is constantly changing in terms of the number of rows and columns of the data

Power query is adding multiple empty columns to the data on import

Ex. If my previous CSV had 7 columns and the newest CSV has only 4 columns

```
First Name, Last Name Email, Segment, Pilot
```

On importing with powor query I get

[image]

you can see the added columns

```
_10, _11, _12
```

Here is my Power Query

```
let
           FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="fp"]}[Content]{0}[TheFilePath],
           Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(FilePath),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
           #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source),each {_,type text})),

           BulkReplaceSyntac = fBulkReplacePart(#"Changed Type", MyFindReplace, Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")),
           #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(BulkReplaceSyntac,"#(00A0)","",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(BulkReplaceSyntac)),
           #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","#(0087)","",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value")),
           #"Replaced Null" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value1")),
           

           #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Replaced Null", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
           #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Promoted Headers", Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"))
        in    #"Removed Errors"
```

The issue seems to be here.

```
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(FilePath),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
```

the `column=7`

How to import only the actual number of columns without having to change the code every time to reflect the new column count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely remove the part that says

```
, Columns=7
```

and make it

```
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(FilePath),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
```